# Overridden function pointer problem at template base class C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance, templates, function-pointers

I implemented a template base class for observer pattern,

```
template<class T>
class ActionListener
{
public:
    ActionListener(void);    
    virtual ~ActionListener(void);    
    void registerListener(T* listener);    
    void unregisterListener(T* listener);

    template<typename Signal>
    void emit(Signal signal);

    template<typename Signal, typename Parameter>
    void emit(Signal signal, const Parameter& parameter);

    template<typename Signal, typename Parameter1, typename Parameter2>
    void emit(Signal signal, 
              const Parameter1& parameter1, 
              const Parameter2& parameter2);

private:
    std::vector<T*> mListenerList;
};

class IEventListener
{
public:
    virtual void messageArrived( Message* message);
    virtual void messageArrived(ClientHandle* handle, Message* message);
};
```

i am using  classes like this

```
emit(&IEventListener::messageArrived, message);
emit(&IEventListener::messageArrived, mHandle, message);
```

the problem here is, compiler cannot deduce template parameters and i couldn't gave template parameters explicitly?

Do someone have an idea ??

EDIT:
Problem here is overridden function calling with template parameters."Emit" function works correctly for other function types.

Usage of this pattern is

```
class SampleClass : public ActionListener<IEventListener>
{
//some stuff here
//this class is observing events of IEventListener
}
```

by the way this is C++.

Comment: Why can't you give the template parameter type explicitly ?

Comment: "...compiler cannot deduce template parameters..." What's the error message?

Comment: I've trouble understanding what you're trying to do. Please add more explanations. You left out the definition of Message and didn't mention how ActionListener should interact with IEventListener. Your code fragments are not exactly self-explanatory. I think you try to emulate Java-style generics here where T is a class type that derives from IEventListener. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEventListener::messageArrived` is overloaded, so the compiler can't determine the type of `&IEventListener::messageArrived`. It could be `void (IEventListener::*)(Message*)` or `void (IEventListener::*)(ClientHandle*, Message*)`.

The straighforward (and ugly) solution is to explicitely cast `&IEventListener::messageArrived` to the desired type at the call site, like this:

```
emit(static_cast<void (IEventListener::*)(Message*)>(&IEventListener::messageArrived), a_message_ptr);
```

or by assigning to a variable of the desired function type:

```
void (IEventListener::*func_ptr)(Message*) = &IEventListener::messageArrived;
emit(func_ptr, a_message_ptr);
```

(Did I say it was ugly?)

The template parameter could also be explicitly specified:

```
emit<void (IEventListener::*)(Message*)>(&IEventListener::messageArrived, a_message_ptr);
```

(Still ugly)

Another imperfect solution is to deduce the type of `Signal` from the type of the listener (`T`) and the other parameters:

```
// Warning: untested. 
// For illustration purposes only
template<class T>
class ActionListener
{
public:
    //...
    void emit(void (T::*signal)());

    template<class Arg1T>
    void emit(void (T::*signal)(Arg1T), Arg1T);

    template<class Arg1T, class Arg2T>
    void emit(void (T::*signal)(Arg1T, Arg2T), Arg1T, Arg2T);
};
```

This is imperfect though because the arguments types must match exactly.

Depending how much change you can make in the design, a simpler solution would be to remove the ambiguity by giving different names to the members of IEventListener. You could also use an already existing signals/slots library, like [Boost.Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/signals2.html)

Comment: Can you add explicit casting here, because i cannot do the cast.thx for all.

Comment: I added examples for explicitly specifying the type by casting, using an intermediate variable, or explicitly stating the template parameter.

Comment: I also added a paragraph at the end of my answer with other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about your example, you're calling

```
emit(&IEventListener::messageArrived, message);
```

which I assume is supposed to match

```
template <class Signal>
ActionListener<T>::void emit(Signal signal);
```

But this overload of `emit` takes only one parameter, what do you think that the `&IEventListener::messageArrived` parameter is used for?

Remember that `IEventListener` is the template parameter for the class `ActionListener` and not for the `emit` function.

When I tried this it works:

```
ActionListener<IEventListener> al;
Message* message = 0;
al.emit(message);
```

Comment: i added some explanations.Message or Clienthandle classes are no need to explain, they are just example classes.